# Any way to check and get NSLayoutConstraint conflicts programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

**EDIT: I updated the question so it is more clear.**

Is there a way to check the constraints and get an `NSArray` of conflicting ones?

I'm working on an [Autolayout helper](https://github.com/fmaylinch/autolayout-helper) class and I would like to print a pretty log when there are conflicts or errors.

By default, when there are layout conflicts you get a log that shows the conflicting constraints like this:

```
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe110638610 UILabel:0x7fe11062bb80'green'.leading == UIView:0x7fe11070de50.leadingMargin>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe1106386b0 H:[UILabel:0x7fe11062bb80'green'(20)]>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe110638660 UIView:0x7fe11070de50.trailingMargin == UILabel:0x7fe11062bb80'green'.trailing>",
"<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fe11063fbe0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Width' H:[UIView:0x7fe11070de50(375)]>"
```

I would like to get those constraints to display them in a prettier way (by view key for example). Any idea on how to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't you just fix the problem, so you don't have conflicts the next time you run the app?

Comment: Yes, haha, sounds reasonable. The thing is that I'm working on an [autolayout helper](https://github.com/fmaylinch/autolayout-helper) class so I would like to present errors in a prettier way. I don't like the logs.

Answer (score 1):

My book provides a couple of utility methods (implemented in a category on NSLayoutConstraint) that I like to use to log constraints when I'm debugging or exploring them:

```
extension NSLayoutConstraint {
    class func reportAmbiguity (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as! [UIView] {
            println("\(vv) \(vv.hasAmbiguousLayout())")
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                self.reportAmbiguity(vv)
            }
        }
    }
    class func listConstraints (var v:UIView?) {
        if v == nil {
            v = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow
        }
        for vv in v!.subviews as! [UIView] {
            let arr1 = vv.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Horizontal)
            let arr2 = vv.constraintsAffectingLayoutForAxis(.Vertical)
            NSLog("\n\n%@\nH: %@\nV:%@", vv, arr1, arr2);
            if vv.subviews.count > 0 {
                self.listConstraints(vv)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks matt, that's useful. Although I have done a test and `hasAmbiguousLayout` seems to return `YES` for all the views **even when there's no conflict**... :(  I would like to get the array of constraints printed by the "default" log.

Comment: Well, you cannot magically intercept the "default" log and recast it somehow. It is what it is. I suggest you learn to read it. It's pretty simple. What I do is use that log _and_ my utilities (and also View Debugging!) to clarify what's going on.

Comment: When you get used to it can be read, but all those hex references are a bit distracting... :(

Comment: But that is how objects are uniquely identified. Without them, you wouldn't know what view this is. That is why my utilities are helpful: they give you the _same_ identifiers, but the order is hierarchical.

Comment: In this case, I could use the view keys you pass to `constraintsWithVisualFormat`. That's what I wanted to do. I'll keep investigating, thanks!

Comment: But the view keys you pass are not present. They were just a shorthand, used to derive the _real_ constraints, which are what you are being shown.

Comment: I keep those keys in my Autolayout helper class.

Comment: That's great but the message coming from the system and going to the console is not passing through your Autolayout helper class, is it? That's the point.

Comment: By the way, what you are asking to do is not at all silly. You have an excellent use case for submitting an enhancement request to Apple. They tell us when constraints are ambiguous; why can't they tell us when they conflict? But they don't.

Comment: I could resolve the views from their internal id I guess, or better if I could get the conflicting constraints. That way I could find the views by reference.   There must be a private method returning the array that the log is printing. If I could get that I'm sure I could do what I want. Thanks!

Comment: "There must be a private method" Right, basically that's what I said in my previous comment. The runtime clearly _has_ this list, so why doesn't it _share_ the list? That is what I'm suggesting you file an enhancement request for.